# Why is Material UI's makestyles not affecting linear progress bar anymore?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My react component for linear progress bar intakes props from the parents to designated the correct color of the bar. This was working up until recently and I can't seem to find a resolution that makes sense.

The odd part is, I can see my makestyles class being created in the css on the browser, yet its being overridden by the primary colors. If I 'hide' the primary background color with browser dev tools all my custom styles show up. Am I missing an override somewhere?

Here is my component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {makeStyles, withStyles} from '@material-ui/styles/'
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },

  linearColorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: "#D7DBDD",

  },
  linearBarColorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: props => props.barColor,
  },
})



function ProgressBar (props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props)
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(0)



  useEffect(() => {
  
if(props.completed !== 0) {

    function progress () {
      setCompleted(props.completed)
  }

      setInterval(progress, 500)
}

  }, [props.completed])



    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <LinearProgress 
          style={{height: "10px",
        }}
          
          classes={{
            colorPrimary: classes.linearColorPrimary,
            barColorPrimary: classes.linearBarColorPrimary,
          }} 
          variant="determinate" value={completed >= 100 ? 100 : completed} />
        </div>

      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
// }

ProgressBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object,
}

export default ProgressBar
```

And the CSS from the browser

```
.MuiLinearProgress-bar1Determinate {
    transition: transform .4s linear;
}
<style>
.MuiLinearProgress-barColorPrimary {
    background-color: #3f51b5;
}
<style>
.MuiLinearProgress-bar {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 0.2s linear;
    transform-origin: left;
}
<style>


.makeStyles-linearBarColorPrimary-5 {
```

<strike>background-color: rgb(232, 25, 68);</strike>

```
}
```

My 'makestyle' is crossed out due to being overridden. How do I get my prop colors back working?

Comment: Change your import to `import {makeStyles, withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles"`. Importing from `@material-ui/styles` introduces the potential to import a different copy of these than what is being used by "@material-ui/core" which can cause the order of styles in the `<head>` to be incorrect (which affects which styles win).

Comment: Ahhh, perfect!! Thank you so much.

I even copied in the material ui example and it wasn't working, I didn't remove my imports though!! Knew it had to be something simple, that resolved it on the example and my code immediately.